# Getting DIV ID on AJAX loaded content

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-post

I have `div` with unique `id` and I'm trying to get that `div` `id` with `jQuery`

```
<div class="quantity" id="UNIQUE_ID">Quantity</div>
```

Everything works good, but after loading `div` with `ajax` - I just can't get `id` from loaded `div`.

```
$('.quantity').click(function() {       
    $.post('quantity.php', { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(output) {
        $(this).html(output);
    }); 
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your `click` function works after loading the content. The problems looks like your `onclick` binding doesn't work after the div gets refreshed. Try using `on()` function of jquery, that might solve your problem

Comment: Question: Why are you using $('.quantity'), and later $('#'+ id) ? You should be using one or the other, not switching back n forth. Answer to problem: Im almost 200% sure that $unique_id is never written out correctly. Fix that, or just use $('.quantity') to add your data like you did when selecting it in the first place.

Comment: Also remember: class = multiple instances, id = unique, so you probably shouldn't be selecting via the class to start with, especially since you already attributed it an id value (which like i said before i'm sure is not written out correctly)

Comment: I'm actually need ID to know what line to load from `MySQL`, and on function not helped much. If I'm loading `script` with content using post - everything works, but I don't want to have repeating script.

Comment: Use data-attributes if storing values. But i'm still sure your id is wrong or invalid (starts with a number, contains invalid characters, etc)

Comment: ID is `quantity_1` (numbers changes with `MySQL` unique ID), I have a table with a lot of lines and don't really want to bind click on every unique ID, the plan is hit the div field to receive ID and load the exact number from `MySQL` database. Everything works, but not with newly loaded content.

Comment: if you inject divs dynamically, then like face was trying to point out, you need to use live() :: $(document).on('click', '.quantity', function(){ ...});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
$('.quantity').click(function() {
    var that = this;        

    $.post('quantity.php', { quantityId: $(that).attr('id') }, function(data) {
        $(that).html(data);
    }); 
});
```

But this is how i'd write it

```
<div class="quantity" data-id='<?=$unique_id?>'>
    Quantity
</div>

$('.quantity').on('click', function() {
    var that = this;        

    $.post('quantity.php', { quantityId: $(that).data('id') }, function(data) {
        $(that).html(data);
    }); 
});
```

And for dynamic divs

```
<div class="quantity" data-id='<?=$unique_id?>'>
    Quantity
</div>

$(document).on('click', '.quantity', function() {
    var that = this;        

    $.post('quantity.php', { quantityId: $(that).data('id') }, function(data) {
        $(that).html(data);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for `data-id` idea - will use that. Sadly it still not working on AJAX loaded content.

Comment: Thanks. Remember classes/id's should reflect actual html/css stuff. Whenever you need to store productId's, or even full JSON objects, data-attributes are your friend. Small tip: data-something="value" is interpreted as a string, data-something='value' is converted to JSON directly letting you skip the JSON.parse stuff

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` binding to your div won't work once the div has been refreshed (it binded on document.ready() right?). The solution will be either to rebind the function to your element every time you change it (a bad one) or use the `on()` function of `jquery`. Example code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.quantity', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');        

    $.post('quantity.php', { quantityId: id }, function(data){
        $('#'+ id).html(data);
    }); 
});
```

**UPDATE:** As discussed in comments, the `on` method should bind to the document as a whole and not the the class to actually work as the deprecated `live()` method.

Comment: doubt it, .click() is nothing more than an internal alias to .on("click")

Comment: you meant .live() == $(document).on('click', '.quantity') ..still doubt it.

Comment: yes, the `on('click', function(){})` is equivalent to the deprecated `live` function of jquery.

Comment: Nope, on() replaces bind(). $(document).on(event, selector)  replaces live()

Comment: If there is only way - rebind every time - nothing much to do then, thanks

Comment: Yes read a little further: $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);

Comment: oh yes my bad! the method should bind to document as a whole.

Comment: actually on() replaces: bind, live, delegate ..it all depends on what you pass it and in which order.

Comment: It is not working, i`m trying to test with alerts - after click nothing happens.

Comment: The update should/will work, but i suggest you use (var that = this), as in my answer for closure reasons and to be on the safe side.

Comment: And by click you mean the second time you click, after an update has been done, right?

Comment: you inverted your event/selector

Comment: Thanks guys, It's actually working now, just update your answer from '.quantity', 'click' to 'click', '.quantity'.

Comment: A facepalm moment :) Apologies for that.